# Getter and Setter in Java

Tags: java

In my code I'm parsing a JSON Object and in a constructor and I'm using get and set methods to assign those values to variables.

Now the problem is the value printed in the set methods return the value in the proper way. But the value which is printed in get methods returning NULL even after assigning those parsed values to them.

Get & set methods
[image: get & set methods]

Output
[image: Output]

Comment: Please post your code and output in the question, instead of linking to images.

Comment: use a library for that task. Do it by hand only if you are studing for school or something like that. I would use a library like Jackson. [Here is a good example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/)

Comment: Please post the code of the methods caller

Answer (score 0):

It seems like  parsed values are not assigning in get methods.

Answer (score -1):

They are primitives - the getter is returning 0, not null.

Concerning JSON objects, I'd recommend using a library such as JSON-java or json-simple. No need to reinvent the wheel.

JSON-java: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java
Json-simpl: https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple

Guava's Gson lib is a valid alternative, too